# Groovy Griffon with Hibernate4 plugin class not found exception

Tags: groovy, griffon, hibernate-4.x

I was looking for a fast and easy way to write a very cross platform desktop application. This leads me to thinking that the JVM is the place to be. Since Groovy (Grails) is used in my workplace I thought I would try Griffon since they claim it is essentially Grails for the desktop.

I wanted a persistence management layer and it doesn't not appear that GORM is showtime ready in this environment so I moved towards hibernate using the Hibernate4 plugin for Griffon.

Not that I've really used Hibernate in general however I believe, based on the guides, that I am doing things correctly. My gatherings indicate that this doesn't support annotations to wire up classes so I am using hbm.xml files.

The provided [sample](https://github.com/aalmiray/griffon_sample_apps/tree/master/persistence/hibernate4) for the plugin isn't complex but I don't understand where I am deviating.

Here is a sample class file as it stands:

```
package gwash

import groovy.beans.Bindable

class DeliveryMethodModel {
   // @Bindable String propName
}
```

Here is some of the stack trace:

```
org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from res
ource gwash\DeliveryMethod.hbm.xml
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Con
figuration.java:3415)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXmlQueu
e(Configuration.java:3404)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(C
onfiguration.java:3392)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:
1341)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.jav
a:1737)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.jav
a:1788)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$buildSessionFactory.call(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at griffon.plugins.hibernate4.Hibernate4Connector.connect(Hibernate4Conn
ector.groovy:72)
        at griffon.plugins.hibernate4.Hibernate4Connector.connect(Hibernate4Conn
ector.groovy)
        at griffon.plugins.hibernate4.Hibernate4Connector$connect.call(Unknown S
ource)
        at Hibernate4GriffonAddon.addonInit(Hibernate4GriffonAddon.groovy:27)
        at griffon.core.GriffonAddon$addonInit.call(Unknown Source)
        at griffon.core.GriffonAddon$addonInit.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.util.AddonHelper.handleAddon(AddonHelper
.groovy:155)
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.util.AddonHelper.handleAddonsAtStartup(A
ddonHelper.groovy:105)
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.DefaultAddonManager.doInitialize(De
faultAddonManager.java:33)
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.AbstractAddonManager.initialize(Abs
tractAddonManager.java:101)
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.util.GriffonApplicationHelper.initialize
AddonManager(GriffonApplicationHelper.java:320)
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.util.GriffonApplicationHelper.prepare(Gr
iffonApplicationHelper.java:123)
        at org.codehaus.griffon.runtime.core.AbstractGriffonApplication.initiali
ze(AbstractGriffonApplication.java:221)
        at griffon.swing.AbstractSwingGriffonApplication.bootstrap(AbstractSwing
GriffonApplication.java:74)
        at griffon.swing.AbstractSwingGriffonApplication.run(AbstractSwingGriffo
nApplication.java:131)
        at griffon.swing.SwingApplication.main(SwingApplication.java:36)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: field [id] not found on gwas
h.DeliveryMethodModel
        at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectProperty
Accessor.java:182)
        at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectProperty
Accessor.java:189)
        at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectProperty
Accessor.java:189)
        at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectProperty
Accessor.java:189)
        at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectProperty
Accessor.java:189)
        at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getField(DirectProperty
Accessor.java:174)
        at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor.getGetter(DirectPropert
yAccessor.java:197)
        at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.getter(ReflectHelper.java:2
53)
        at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.reflectedPropertyClass(Refl
ectHelper.java:229)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.setTypeUsingReflection(SimpleValue.
java:326)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindSimpleId(HbmBinder.java:449)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues(HbmBi
nder.java:382)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRootClass(HbmBinder.java:322)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindRoot(HbmBinder.java:173)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processHbmXml(Con
```

My xml mapping file:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="gwash">
    <class name="DeliveryMethodModel" table="[DELIVERY METHODS]">
        <id name="id" column="[DELIVERY METHOD ID]">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="method" column="[DELIVERY METHOD]"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

EDIT: I've removed the brackets and spaces as indicated. Changed the DataSource.groovy to 'create' on the DB side. Still experiencing the same issues. The examples for hibernate integration with griffon/hsqldb/groovy are scant on details. Do I need to create all given properties for the model files for this to parse correctly? I've never used hibernate. Nor groovy. Nor griffon. I would definitely provide feedback for the community if I can get this resolved, if not I'll be rolling me own ORM since this is a rather small project. Rather not roll me own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you actually have the strings wrapped with `[`and `]`?

I would suspect that for a class defined as

```
package gwash
import groovy.beans.Bindable
class DeliveryMethodModel {
    Long id
    @Bindable String method
}
```

the mapping file would be

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="gwash">
    <class name="DeliveryMethodModel" table="DELIVERY_METHODS">
        <id name="id" column="DELIVERY_METHOD_ID">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property name="method" column="DELIVERY_METHOD"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Is it possibly an issue the table names were defined with spaces? The brackets were just something I was trying. Those strings didn't originally have that and still generated errors.

Comment: PS: I should add that the database is HSQLDB based originally designed in LibreOffice. The table names have spaces in them.

Comment: I can confirm that having spaces in the table names leads to weird problems, both with HSQLDB and H2.

Comment: did you come to any solutions regarding it or did you have to rename your tables?

Comment: I renamed the tables to avoid having any spaces and non-alphanumeric characters.

Comment: This could very well be the answer I'm looking for. I'll give it a go this evening and get back to this.

Comment: I removed the brackets and have renamed my tables but I'm still getting a very similar result. My first instinct was to start with a blank slate DB. I set DataSource.groovy to 'create'. My understanding is that it should create a fresh db with this schema. Still fails parsing the same hbm.xml file with the same message.

Comment: PS: Do I need to declare the properties in the Model classes for this compile to work? The documentation on the plugin is lacking and I have 0% hibernate experience otherwise.

Comment: Yes, you must have the same properties defined on the model class as in the mapping file. Be advised by Griffon Model classes != domain classes like in Grails, they are presentation models, hence why this plugin does not provide GORM like behavior. The hibernate4 plugin docs assumes some working knowlegde of Hibernate from the developer's part as it just provides the means to connect to DBs via hibernate; the problem so far has been understanding mapping file syntax. We're currently working on a GORM like API for Griffon but is not yet ready for public usage.